# PartialView as HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok.. here we go.. the weirdest and most confusing question of the month :)
I would like to create a HtmlHelper that some how renders html, but uses a partial view for its template of how the html should be rendered, so to put it more simple.. I would like to do exactly the same as a "normal" Controller and view does.. get some data, pass it to the view and then render the html, but in this case I would like to pass some data to a partial view, and then get the returned html as a string and then return that html from a HtmlHelper method...
In this way I would like to be able to write for instance @Html.HeadMenu, that then would return the html for the headmenu, but I would also be able to at anytime without recompiling be able to change the html.. since its all in a partial view.. and I wont have to worry about any server-side things.. and I will also get the benefit of the intellisense since my method will show up in @Html.

I hope you will understand this..since its kind of hard to explain..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.aspx) HTML-extension method, it sounds like what you are trying to achive right?

```
@{
var htmlString = Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName").ToString();
}
```

It also has an overload so that you can pass a model to the partial view:

```
@{
var htmlString = Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName", partialViewModel).ToString();
}
```

Comment: You'd also have to call either ToHtmlString() or ToString() to get an actual string (the method return a MvcHtmlString.

Comment: Might work.. but what if I would like to do something like:
namespace PMT.Core.Helpers
{
    public class MenuHelper
    {
        public static string HeadMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
           return Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName", partialViewModel).ToHtmlString();
        }
    }
}

might not be the best example but Ill guess you get the idea :)

Comment: found it :P.. Ill try your approach now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could be looking for the `Html.RenderAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues)` method.

Answer (score 0):

**I would do it this way**

Define data that you imagine to pass to your htmlhelper

```
public class HeadMenuViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Define view named `HeadMenuViewModel.cshtml` in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`

```
@model HeadMenuViewModel
<div>
 ////
</div>
```

From now, you can display your data using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HeadMenu)
```

And you could write named shortcut-extension for it

```
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
...
    public static MvcHtmlString HeadMenu<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
       return helper.DisplayFor(expression);
    }
```

Now, change your `HeadMenuViewModel.cshtml` everytime you need to